# Access 2013 Insert / update

Tags: insert, updates, ms-access-2013

I have a form to add user.

I can add, delete rows in the table however I pretend to update if the user already exist.

My goal is press the row in sub form to edit. 
but every time I press update it gives me an error.

> Run-time error '3075' Syntax error operator in query expression.

the action code I have is this

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'quando se carrega em Adicionar há 2 opcoes
    '1-Insert
    '2-Update
    If Me.txtuserid.Tag & "" = "" Then

        '1
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO user(userid, username, userfunction, usercc) " & _
                " VALUES(" & Me.txtuserid & ",'" & Me.txtusername & "','" & Me.txtuserfun & "','" & Me.txtusercc & "')"
     Else
     '2
     CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE user " & _
            " SET userid=" & Me.txtuserid & _
            ", username=" & Me.txtusername & "'" & _
            ", userfunction =" & Me.txtuserfun & "'" & _
            ", usercc =" & Me.txtusercc & "'" & _
            " WHERE userid =" & Me.txtuserid.Tag
      End If
    'clear fields
    cmdClear_Click
    'refresh
    SubForm1.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you miss `'` in you update statement;

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE user " & _
        " SET userid=" & Me.txtuserid & _
        ", username='" & Me.txtusername & "'" & _
        ", userfunction ='" & Me.txtuserfun & "'" & _
        ", usercc ='" & Me.txtusercc & "'" & _
        " WHERE userid =" & Me.txtuserid.Tag
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot... that's right @Praveen I will mark your answered correct